# HAXM is installed but emulator not running

Tags: java, android, eclipse, emulation, haxm

I recently upgraded my CPU from core2duo E4600 to E6550. E6550 is supports virtualization. Then i install HAXM intel hardware acceleration manager.Installation was successful. People on youtube and many other sites says it fast the emulator but in my case my emulator is not even starting.. I have this configuration of device [image]

**AVD doesn't even show that "A valid android virtual device" in the bottom... it shows two options only** 
[image]

Please suggest me... how to run my emulator.. i have searched a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an x86 system image like this one:
 [image]

You can download x86 images in the SDK manager (the one shown contains Google Play which is a bonus if you need to have it on your emulator).

[image]

The "errors" at the bottom of your window aren't errors.  What you're seeing is a poorly designed key for what any icons that appear next to your devices may mean.

Comment: i just open stackoverflow and i am trying your solution hope it will worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps need to create, not edit, an AVD?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the memory used by HAXM.
You can find the guidelines in Configuring VM Acceleration on Windows section of this page: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of andoid studio you have installed is it lower than what the render supports?

Because I also had the same issue and what solved it was just uninstalling the android studio I initally installed and installing the one that was compatible version wise.

My Old Installation that didn't work despite all my efforts, thinking my installed haxm was faulty or not working was

- android-studio-bundle-141.2456560-windows

So I uninstalled the above and installed the one below before it started working.

- android-studio-bundle-141.2117773-windows

Not really sure why that solved it even though the one i uninstalled seems to be more recent than that of the previous one. But that solved it and so it seems there are version compatibility issues.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Download the HAXM installer on the intel website and install

https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases

`Windows`

Run the haxm-7.6.6-setup.exe to install HAXM

`Mac OS`

I am not quite sure.